# Definition of finitely generated model

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

Let $M$ be a model of an algebraic theory $\mathcal T$. $M$ is said to be *finitely generated* if it is the quotient of a free model $F(n)$ over a finite set $n$. Here, quotient means there exists a regular epi $F(n)\twoheadrightarrow M$, (i.e this epi is a cokernel).

From the adjunction $F\dashv U$, this arrow corresponds to an arrow $n\rightarrow U(M)$, which is just an $n$-tuple $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$. Hence, it seems to me that the condition $M$ be a quotient of a free model over a finite set can be replaced simply by "there is an arrow to $M$ from a free model over a finite set".

What am I missing? Why should $M$ indeed be a *quotient*? I thought finitely generated was exactly about specifying arrows = specifying images of the basis.

Comment: Do you know what, say, a finitely generated group is? It includes the condition that the tuple $u_1, \dots u_n$ generates the group, which is equivalent to the corresponding map $F_n \to G$ being surjective. You can't just specify some arbitrary tuple.

Comment: I understand. How can I see the equivalence formally?

Comment: For groups you should show that regular epi is equivalent to surjective.